# Hyperlink to an excel shape from a cell

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I am having this problem from a long time without any solution.

I have a cell A3 in '**Sheet 1**' and a shape '**Rectangle1**' in '**Sheet 2**'.
We all know about hyperlinks from one cell to another cell, but i really didn't find any method to hyperlink from cell A3 to shape 'Rectangle1', so that when i click the hyperlink in cell A3, it will take me directly to 'Rectangle 1'.

I am not asking about value linking between cells and shapes, rather the hyperlink from cell to a shape.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink Workbook function.

Set the cell hyperlink to a convenient cell on the sheet with the shape. Select the shape in the Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink function like so:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)    
    Range(Target.SubAddress).Worksheet.Shapes("Rectangle 1").Select
End Sub
```

This should get you started

-OO-